# Index of element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 100 rows and 10 columns.Now I know a value in column A and would like to know the value of column B in the same row.Could some one tell me the way please

I tried using the index method as `idx=df["column A"].index("value")`
`df[idx]["column B"]` but showing error

Comment: Read upon [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). You can do `df.loc[df['A'].eq(value), 'B']`

Comment: Thanks for the lead,although I had used a for loop to get the index which is working fine now ,but loc() method is still showing error.And also one more question isn't loc() method written using for loop

Comment: @mechanics please provide minimal reproducible code/sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, the purpose of `pandas` is to help you with managing data. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Generating 100 rows, 10-column random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

#only return A and B column
print(df[["A","B"]])

#Return the B column only if the value of column A greater than 50
print(df.loc[df["A"]>50,["B"]])

#Return column B only for the range 5 to 10
print(df.iloc[5:10]["B"])

#Return columns A, and B when the value of A is between 50 to 60
print(df.loc[df['A'].between(50, 60),["A","B"]])

#Return columns A and B only for five first and last rows
print(df.loc[np.r_[0:5, 95:100], ["A","B"]])
```

You can do many more; check the doc of [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for more detail